# Listando dados de uma tabela com PHP

Tags: php, pdo

Olá, estou tentando fazer uma listagem com dados em uma tabela com o código abaixo, mas não estou conseguindo. Já fiz de várias maneiras, vi tutoriais na internet e tudo mais, porém, não dá em nada. No servidor tanto local quanto o externo não aparece nada, fica tudo branco. Alguém poderia me informar se tem algum erro nesse código?

```
    <?php
    require_once("Conn.php");
    $conexao = conectar();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tab_final";
        try{
            $selecionar = $conexao->prepare($query);
            $selecionar->execute();
            $select = $selecionar->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
          foreach($select as $listar){
            echo "Times: ".$listar->Nome."<br />";
          }
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();

     }
    ?>
```

Usei até o FETCH_ASSOC e mudei o echo para ficar de acordo com o mesmo e nada. Não sei mais o que fazer. Se alguém puder testar e conseguir, me ajuda, por favor! Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É muito simples fazer uma simples listagem usando PHP + MySQL. Se é iniciante, aconselho você primeiro fazer tudo numa página, depois você pode ir organizando de acordo o padrão que quiser. Veja abaixo um exemplo bem simples:

Exemplo de conexão:

```
<?php
// Instancia o objeto PDO
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'root', '');
// define para que o PDO lance exceções caso ocorra erros
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
?>
```

A forma mais simples de ser executada uma consulta seria utilizando query conforme o exemplo:

```
<?php
// executa a instrução SQL
$consulta = $pdo->query("SELECT fullname, email FROM user;");
?>
```

Para obter os dados pode ser utilizado um while percorrendo assim cada linha retornada do banco de dados:

```
<?php
while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // aqui eu mostro os valores de minha consulta
    echo "Fullname: {$linha['fullname']} - email: {$linha['E-mail']}<br />";
}
?>
```

Coloquei o código completo no GitHub como [**ConsultaPDO.php**](https://github.com/cleidimarviana/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/ConsultaPDO.php) para ficar registrado.

Você pode ver mais detalhes em *[PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.query.php)*<sup>(en)</sup> e [*PDO:Query*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.query.php)<sup>(en)</sup>.

Comment: Muito obrigado, Ack. Estudei seu código e consegui, agora está listando os dados da tabela.